# How does amazon book orders by feature?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

**Note:** I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I don't know any other places. If you know other places which are more proper for this question, please tell me.

For example, for [this link](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_il_to_stripbooks?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_n_publication_date%3A1250227011&ie=UTF8&qid=1489919453&lo=none).

[image]

It is sorted by **feature**.

I want to know, how does the sort by feature works. Is there any way I can know it, or anything similar to it?

Comment: No - it is sorted with *feature**d*** books first.  I would guess these are books which Amazon wants to promote for one reason or another (advertising deals with publishers, excess stock, etc) and are slightly related to whatever you searched for

Answer (score 0):

As Henry wrote in the comment, the word on that page is actually **featured**, and they are probably products that Amazon wants to promote. The exact method is likely a trade secret, but I can imagine that Amazon has a list of such products, and then ranks it by the closest match to your search query. It could also be a combination of that, and popularity, since it shows me a bunch of books on that link with 'Best Seller' written for each.

In fact, I noticed that it doesn't give me that option when I search for something, only when I search across *all* products in a category (Books in your example). So it probably doesn't even try to make them relevant to my search query, just a ranking of products within a category, that satisfy some secret criteria like products Amazon wants to push, or popularity, or something like that.